# Prove that any finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness

I saw some other ways of doing this proof but wanted to see if my strategy could work:

Need to show $S$, a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, is bounded and closed for it to be compact.

Let $D$ be the set of all Euclidean distances between points in $S$. Since $S$ is finite, it has a finite number of unique pairs of its elements, so $D$ is finite. Since $D$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$, it must then be bounded and by the completeness axiom have a maximum element. Set $c = \max[D]$ and then we have for all $x \in S$, $d(x_i,x_j) \leq c$ where $d$ is the Eucliean distance between $x_i$ and $x_j$. Hence by definition $S$ is bounded.

Let $z \in bdy(S)$ and assume $z \in S^c$. Let $E$ be the set of all Euclidean distances between $z$ and elements of $S$.  Similar to above, $E$ will be finite, bounded, and therefore have a minimum element $m$. Let $\varepsilon = \frac{m}{2}$ and consider the ball $B(z, \varepsilon)$ centered at $z$ with radius $\varepsilon$. Then $B(z,\varepsilon) \cap S = \emptyset$ since $z \notin S$ and $\varepsilon < m$. Hence by definition $z \notin bdy(S)$, contradicting our assumption. Therefore, $z \in S$ and by definition $S$ is closed.

Conclude that since $S$ is bounded and closed, it is compact. $\Box$

Comment: What you did is fine. Just to add any finite set is compact in any topological space, even ones where bounded and closed sets aren't necessarily compact.

Comment: Good to know! In my elementary topology class we have not discussed topological spaces yet, so I have to explain myself more fully and using tools we've covered.

Comment: Looks good. Other than that, be careful about the extent of what you use. The completeness axiom tells you things about infinite sets--- every finite set of numbers has a maximum element, so it's not really needed here.

Comment: Any finite subset of any space is compact according to the topological definition that a set S is compact iff every open cover of S has a finite sub-cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your proof seems correct. What you essentially did was applied the [Heine--Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) and used it to prove the statement, which is great, but maybe a bit of an overkill. A simpler solution to this is to just construct a finite subcover of any given open cover of the finite subset $S$. If $\{U_\alpha\}$ is a collection of open sets covering $S=\{s_1,s_2,\dots,s_k\}$ then just pick $U_i$ for each $1\leq i\leq k$ to contain $s_i$, and then $\{U_1,U_2,\dots,U_k\}$ is trivially a finite subcover, proving the result.

This proof works in general topological spaces, as we did not use any property specific to $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: That certainly works as well. In my Real Analysis class we used that particular definition of compact. However in my Topology class we were given the Heine-Borel thm. as the definition of compact (along with boundary defined using Euclidean distance), so that's the direction I took.

Comment: @pyridoxal_trigeminus Oh, I see. In that case then your approach makes a lot of sense. I was assuming the open cover definition as that is normally the one that is used (because it generalises to topological spaces).